# django-admin startproject not working with python3 on OS X

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have python3 installed with Django 1.8.2 on Mac OS. There is also python 2.7 installed by default with the OS. When trying to run startproject I get -

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

It is likely defaulting to the system's python 2.7 which does not have django. How do I force it to use python3? I tried aliasing python to python3 in the shell but that didn't work either.

Comment: You are executing the django-admin command using python2. Try activate your virtualenv first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recommended:** Try using **virtualenv** and initiate your environment with Python3.

Or a quicker solution is to use python interpreter directly to execute django-admin:

```
<path-to-python3>/python /usr/local/bin/django-admin startproject mysite
```